# Editing NSMutableDictionary from another method

Tags: objective-c

I want to be able to acess and edit a NSMutableDictionary from multiple methods inside the same class. I got part of what I want working inside a single method but I need to be able to edit the dictionary from multiple methods. Can someone please give me of an example of a NSMutableDictionary that is accesible throughout a class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your `.h` file:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *myDict;
}
```

The `myDict` object will be visible for all your instance methods.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did what you said and the other methods recognize the fact that it exists but i cant seem to add anything too it. When I set up the dictionary in the method i used     NSMutableDictionary *anotherDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
is there a way to use your suggestion in a way to have the same affect?

Comment: In one of your methods, you need to initialize it like this: `myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`

Comment: Thank you so much. As you can tell im learning and little things like this drive me crazy. Thanks